# array split 2 ,3 length using PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like `$array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];` and I want to split it as 3,2 length:

```
  $array=[
      array(1,2,3),
      array(4,5),
      array(6,7,8),
      array(9,10),
   ]
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried already? The PHP manual is _quite_ comprehensive, with lots of user-contributed tips and tricks, and the web has quite a few search engines available (including Stackoverflow's own search), so: what solutions have you found as part of your [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask), and how did those not do what you were hoping to do?

Comment: You need to learn about loops and count variables to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

array_splice() can help to grab alternatively 2 or 3 items from your array, and put them in a new array.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$out   = array();
$step  = true;
while (count($array)) {
    $out[] = array_splice($array, 0, $step ? 3 : 2);
    $step  = !$step;
}
```

`$out` will be `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]`...

doc : https://php.net/array_splice

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$slices = [3, 2];
$sliced = [];

$i = 0;

while ($i < count($array)) {
    foreach ($slices as $length) {
        $sliced[] = array_slice($array, $i, $length);
        $i += $length;
    }
}

print_r($sliced);
```